# indexing a FK in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I have table1 with uniquely indexed PK on ColA.

I have table2 with uniquely indexed PK on ColA and ColB

I add FK to table2 on ColA back to table1.

I know that I should have indexes on foreign key columns.
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=201154
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:292016138754
according to the above articles.

My question is the index on the PK for table2 good enough to satisfy that requirement. The index should be in the order of ColA,ColB so it should be able to use that as a index for the FK because the ColA comes first. right?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks guys, that's what I thought, but I wanted to make sure... high volume tables... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right.  There should be no need for a separate index on ColA in table2.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct - Oracle will be able to use the leading edge (i.e. ColA) of the existing index and any remaining fields (i.e. ColB) in the index will not matter much (they will slightly "widen" the index but the price you pay for that is much less than what you would pay for a separate index).